# Audience Management

Tags: audience-manager

I have a contact in one of my Address book and have assigned this Address book to 2 different publications.
Now I want to localise this Address book in both the publications to provide one new attribute(property) to my contact in both. Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Thanks Wills. Let me further elaborate my question. 
1) Created a new attribute for Contacts globally 
2) Created a contact in  a Global Address book
3)Assigned this Global address book to lets say two publications US and UK.
4)I want to provide a value in new attribute(step 1) in the Contact created in Step 2 only for UK and not for US publication. 
Can this be possible. A kind of localisation of a Contact.
I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

The contact profile is global, so applies to all contacts in all address books. It should then just be a case of adding the new attribute globally - you cannot have address book specific properties.

Comment: Thanks Wills. Let me further elaborate my question. 1) Created a new attribute for Contacts globally 2) Created a contact in a Global Address book 3)Assigned this Global address book to lets say two publications US and UK. 4)I want to provide a value in new attribute(step 1) in the Contact created in Step 2 only for UK and not for US publication. Can this be possible. A kind of localisation of a Contact. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: No - the contact profile is global, so anything added in one publication, you see in the other as well...